# kioclient KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses" refers to unknown mimetype "application/vnd.ms-excel..."

Tags: kde, mime-types, xdg-open

Whenever I open something with xdg-open in my new OpenSUSE 13.2 install, I am spammed by a sequence of warnings like

```
$ xdg-open ./flask.wsgi
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(10634) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12"
```

This occurs regardless of what file/type I'm opening with xdg-open. This is a big nuisance because in some of my programs these warnings get rendered to the screen. The error never occured on my Fedora KDE setup. How can I fix these warnings? What is missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343468
You can use a workaround as described in the #3
`sudo sed -i 's:macroEnabled:macroenabled:g' /usr/share/mime/subclasses`